# Isolating Strings Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, find

I'm trying to extract dimensions which are listed on a webpage using  BeautifulSoup. My aim, for now, is to append the measurements to a list. The dimensions I am after occur on lines which look like the following:

```
#Where the dimensions are `12.7x108mm` and `40x46 mm` respectively:

<td><a href="/12.7x108mm" title="12.7x108mm">12.7x108mm</a>

<td><a href="/40x46_mm" title="40x46 mm">40x46 mm</a>
```

However, using...

```
measurements_list = soup.find_all('td', href="", title="")
```

...returns about a third of the page, including mostly unwanted data.

I attempted to create a loop which excludes any lines with `class` in them, as I thought that would get rid of 90% of the extraneous HTML lines:

```
dimensions_list = []
for data in soup.find_all('td', href="", title=""):
    if not data.find({'class': ''}):
        dimensions_list.append(data)
```

However, this doesn't seem to have any effect on lines containing `class`. Last time I approached a similar task I gave-in and turned the HTML into a string and hacked it into little pieces until I got what I wanted.

What's the appropriate way to do extract these dimensions, or at least refine the results?

---

[Link to my HTML `soup` on Pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/hCUUzJkX)

---

This will replicate my soup and attempted solution:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/Ammunition"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#First Attempt
dimensions_list = soup.find_all('td', href="", title="")

#Second Attempt
dimensions_list = []
for info in soup.find_all('td', href="", title=""):
    if not info.find('td', {'class': ''}):
        dimensions_list.append(info)
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what do you currently get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about matching by element and a pattern?

Try this:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/Ammunition")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

dimensions_list = soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == "a" and re.search(r"\d\s?mm", t.text))

for anchor in dimensions_list:
    try:
        print(anchor["title"])
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

Output:

```
7.62x25mm Tokarev
9x18mm Makarov
9x19mm Parabellum
9x21mm Gyurza
4.6x30mm HK
5.7x28mm FN
5.45x39mm
5.56x45mm NATO
7.62x39mm
7.62x51mm NATO
7.62x54mmR
9x39mm
12.7x55mm STs-130
12.7x108mm
12x70mm
20x70mm
23x75mm
30x29mm
40x46 mm
7.62x25mm Tokarev
9x18mm Makarov
9x19mm Parabellum
9x21mm Gyurza
4.6x30mm HK
5.7x28mm FN
5.45x39mm
7.62x39mm
7.62x54mmR
9x39mm
12.7x55mm STs-130
12.7x108mm
5.56x45mm NATO
7.62x51mm NATO
12x70mm
12x70 7mm Buckshot
12/70 8.5 mm "Magnum" Buckshot
12x70 6.5 mm "Express" Buckshot
12/70 5.25mm Buckshot
20x70mm
20x70 7.5mm Buckshot
20/70 7.3mm Buckshot
20/70 6.2mm Buckshot
20/70 5.6mm Buckshot
23x75mm
30x29mm
40x46 mm
```

Comment: Thank you, that's much more sophisticated than just cutting up strings over the course of 40 lines!